# Dumping RRC packets

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I am trying to capture RRC messages sending in/out of a container using tcpdump. I cannot find the proper filter for that. I tried to run tcpdump inside the container by `tcpdump -i any rrc`. However,I get this error: `tcpdump: can't parse filter expression: syntax error`.